# multicast not working in two segment network

Tags: routing, multicast, pim

I have two network segments connected to a single Cisco router by Cisco switches. I've enabled multicast routing on the router by running following commands:

1. `ip multicast-routing` in configuration mode
2. `ip pim dense-mode` on each interface

And set following route on the hosts for multicast traffic:

1. `route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev eth2`

According to my searches the multicast traffic should cross the networks without setting `route` for their network (`128.238.61.0` and `128.238.62.0` here),  but is not the case. I tried following solutions, but neither worked:

1. Using `sparse-mode` and `dense-sparse-mode` for interfaces
2. Enabling and disabling `Reverse path filtering` from `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/[all,defalut,eth2]/rp_filter` by writing `0` and `2` in it.

I use `netspy` to create multicast traffic and groups (`224.111.111.111`) and I've verified that the corresponding address is in the multicast groups of router interfaces. Also hosts inside a single network segment can see the multicast traffic properly. As I think the traffic should cross the networks without setting `route`, what misconfigurations may cause this problem. Thank you in advance.

There is one router with interface IPs: `128.238.61.1/24` and `128.238.62.1/24`. To each port of the router a switch is connected. To each switch three hosts are connected. I connect to router by telnet and then type `config term`. Then I type `ip multicast-routing`. I go to interfaces with command `int fa 0/0 (0/1)` and type `ip pim dense-mode`. Then on the host with ip `128.238.61.109/24` I start `netspy` by typing `netspyd 224.111.111.111 1500 6` (parameters are group ip, port and ttl). Now on all other hosts I type `netspy 224.111.111.111 1500`. Now if I `telnet` from one of the hosts on the same side as the `netspyd` to it (`109`) nothing happens. If I set on all hosts route `route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev eth2` and then do the `telnet` hosts on the same side of as the `netspyd` server (network `61.0`) get the message about the log on but others don't.

Best,

Comment: Do a `show running-configuration` and paste that in to your question. You don't need to configure PIM unless you are connecting this router to another router in order to route multicast to the other router. As I wrote a couple of times, PIM is a router-to-router protocol. You need to be concerned with IGMP, and I don't see where you are configuring that.

Comment: Thank you. To configure IGMP for router I searched right now and found this link [conf igmp](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/nx-os/multicast/configuration/guide/b_multicast/b_multicast_chapter_011.html#concept_69382B7C152648128F6D982939C9A861). Is it sufficient to give command `ip igmp version  value` to router in order to config it? For hosts I found [this](https://sites.google.com/site/miclinuxcorner/technology/multicast-routing) which says to set `route`. 
Currently I can't send the output of that command, but I will add it.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how multicast works. The router will not forward the multicast traffic from one interface to the other unless a host in the receiving network has sent an IGMP join message to the router. The host will not do that unless it is running an application which joins the multicast group. You don't list the applications you are using for multicast. You have an application on one side which generates multicast traffic for a specific group. On the other side, you need a host with an application which joins that group. You don't seem to know how this really works.

Comment: You don't seem to have an application which joins the multicast group and sends IGMP to the router. The idea of multicast is that it is a selective broadcast; hosts ignore multicasts unless they have actually subscribed to the multicast group. You need a proper multicast source, and an application on the hosts to receive the multicasts. There are tools to do this if you search the Internet.

Comment: Isn't the `netspy` is that application? According to my experiments the multicast send and receive works  with `netspy` within a single network and after setting the route for `224.111.111.111`.

Comment: You are setting the route because NetSpy is not really a multicast tool, and it isn't joining the multicast group. A proper multicast test tool will obviate your need for setting the multicast route on the hosts. You can send multicasts, and the hosts which have subscribed to the multicast group will receive the multicasts, and the hosts which have not subscribed will ignore the multicasts. Your link about setting the route has to do with using Linux to route, but you have a Cisco router to route. This site isn't designed to teach you about multicast. You should move this discussion to [chat].

Comment: Ok, I will search for `netspy` replacements and I will continue this discussion in the chat room. Many thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31610/discussion-between-mahdi-dolati-and-ron-maupin).

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIM is a router-to-router protocol. I think what you are missing is IGMP. The clients wanting to receive traffic from a multicast groups will use IGMP to inform the router that they wish to receive the traffic:

[image]

Based on your configuration commands, I assume you are using a Cisco router. Cisco has a [document](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/ip/configuration/guide/fipr_c/1cfmulti.html) which describes all of this and how to configure multicast routing.

Comment: Thank you, I read the article, and yes I use Cisco. The `route` for `224.0.0.0` was placed on the hosts and they could send and receive `IGMP` messages (checked by wireshark) and when I run `show ip igmp group` on the interfaces of the router I can see multicast address (`224.111.111.111`) on both. Can't I say that `IGMP` is properly configured?

Comment: Why are you placing a route `224.0.0.0` on the hosts? Multicast doesn't route like that since the hosts are receiving multicast; even on a router you use `mroute` instead of `route`. You didn't show your configurations so that we can see where you may have gone wrong. You should also use a proper multicast address from the Administratively Scoped range (`239.0.0.0/8`) because randomly picking multicast addresses can cause problems.

Comment: As the network space of hosts differ from multicast space, If I don't add `route` how multicast packets are routed? I think all class D addresses ranging from `224.0.0.0` to `239.255.255.255` are for multicast, so used `224.0.0.0`.
And that's pretty much all of my configurations: `multicast` on router, `pim` on interfaces and `route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev eth2` on hosts. Also my hosts are connected to router via switches, do I need to enable `CGMP`?

Comment: You don't put a multicast route on the hosts. Hosts receive multicasts for groups to which they subscribe. PIM isn't needed on the router unless you are routing multicasts to another router; PIM is a router-to-router protocol. CGMP isn't necessary for multicast to work, it allows a switch to disable multicasts on ports for which nothing has subscribed to a multicast group. You need to edit your question with the actual configurations so that we can see where you may have gone wrong. Telling us what you have configured, and what you actually configured, can be very different.

Comment: Dear Ron, I added more details about what I'm doing. Furthermore, today I checked that without setting route for `224.0.0.0` even the hosts on the same network cannot see the multicast traffic from the `netspy` server which sends multicast traffic. So I think the route is necessary. Thank you.

Comment: No, you don't need to set that route on the hosts. The application which wants to join the multicast group will handle that. People use multicast applications all the time without adding a multicast route to their hosts. A host will ignore any multicasts for groups to which it has not subscribed. That is the whole point of multicast.